# matplotlib.mlab.specgram equivalent in Java

Tags: java, python, matplotlib, fft

Is there any similar libraries in Java that can do what [`specgram`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram) function of `matplotlib` library does?

`specgram` splits the data into specified length segments and calculates spectrum of each section, applies a window function to each segment. It also applies a function named `detrend`.

`specgram` returns *(spectrum, freqs, t)*, described as:

> **spectrum**: 2-D array columns are the periodograms of successive
>   segments
>
> **freqs**: 1-D array The frequencies corresponding to the rows in spectrum
>
> **t**: 1-D array The times corresponding to midpoints of segments (i.e the
>   columns in spectrum).

Even if there is not a similar library, what is the way to achieve this? I assume there are lots of FFT libraries for Java. Is the following a correct approach? What I need is actually the `spectrum` (periodograms) that is returned by `specgram`.

- Split data into chunks of specified length
- Apply FFT function on each chunk
- Apply window function (Hanning Window) on each chunk
- ?